# A record pointing VS full DNS change

Tags: url, dns, a-records

I have a domain through **Namecheap**, using basic DNS. I also use **Gmail Business** *(with its MX records)*, and **DigitalOcean** for hosting.

DigitalOcean [wiki](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean) suggests that I should transfer my DNS to DigitalOcean, and then assign my Domain to a Droplet. But then I would have to change my MX servers inside the DigitalOcean server.

Which option is better?

Do a **DNS change** to DigitalOcean servers and point the MX to Gmail from there?

`or`

Leave my DNS as is (basic Namecheap), with MX pointing to Gmail, and simply create **A records pointing** to the DigitalOcean Server?

Is one faster than the other? Will I create potential headache for me in the future *(if I change servers)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference - if it ain't broke, don't fix it. Just add the A record, and if in the future comes up a reason to change DNS provider, you can do it then.